# How to get the needed varibales due to the condition?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have lists with values like this for example:

```
values = [value_one, value_two, list_A[], list_B[], list_C[]]
```

... which are in a map (all these lists have the same structure as the example above, but with different values!):

```
{
   key_one: valuesA,
   key_two: valuesB,
   key_three: valuesC,
   key_four: valuesD,
   key_five: valuesE,
   ...: ...,
   ...: ...
}
```

I also have this function:

```
def calculate_process(map):
    for key, data in map.iteritems():
        value_one, value_two, list_A[], list_B[], list_C[] = data
        # do some calculation
        # ...
        # ...
```

**My problem:**

Due to my code, I want (depends on what condition it is) to get only certain lists. So the code should be more like this:

**Condition 1? Do:**

```
def calculate_process(map):
        for key, data in map.iteritems():
            value_one, value_two, list_A[], list_B[] = data
            # do some calculation
            for value_first, value_second in zip(list_A[], list_B[])
                result = (value_one * value_two + value_first) * value_second
                # more other calculation
                # ...
```

**Condition 2? Do:**

```
def calculate_process(map):
        for key, data in map.iteritems():
            value_one, value_two, list_B[], list_C[] = data
            # do some calculation
            for value_first, value_second in zip(list_B[], list_C[])
                result = (value_one * value_two + value_first) * value_second
                # more other calculation
                # ...
```

**Condition 3? do:**

```
def calculate_process(map):
        for key, data in map.iteritems():
            value_one, value_two, list_A[], list_C[] = data
            # do some calculation
            for value_first, value_second in zip(list_A[], list_C[])
                result = (value_one * value_two + value_first) * value_second
                # more other calculation
                # ...
```

But I don't want to have three function, that does the same (because to have one function is way better), only what different is, is that I have to use different lists. I know, I could just write at the parameter something like "**list_to_not_use=list_B**", but I still have to do (here as an example) three "**if**" condition and could get so the certain lists, which I need.

But imagine, that this list structure..

```
values = [value_one, value_two, list_A[], list_B[], list_C[]]
```

.. would be more like this...:

```
values = [value_one, value_two, list_A[], list_B[], list_C[], list_D[], list_E[], ..., ...]
```

...yes, unknown endless list.

So the solution above (with the **list_to_not_use**) is at this situation not that good, because you would have to do more and more new "**if**" condition.

**My question:**

Is there a super good "impressive" solution, to solve this problem? Or is this such an easy question that you could solve it with ease, that I never have seen a programming code before?

I hope you understand my problem here and I hope you can help me there.

I also would appreciate some code examples :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could alter `calculate_process` to take a second argument, which is a list of keys to ignore from the provided map.

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine under different conditions which lists to be extracted before do_calculate, I suggest you use the positions of lists in the `data` tuple to extract them.

```
def positions_of_list():
    # conditions
    return pos1, pos2

def calculate_process(map):
    for key, data in map.iteritems():
        pos1, pos2 = positions_of_list()
        v1 = data[0]
        v2 = data[1]
        l1 = data[pos1]
        l2 = data[pos2]
        # do calculate thereafter
```

function `positions_of_list` return positions of lists in `data` tuple.

Thanks